# Render json is not defined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anybody explain to me the following scenario in a react-js context:
I work with webpack and use the presets "babel-preset-env" & "react".

On top of a file I import a config.json which I try to inspect with the developer tools and a debugger-statement.

The console.log logs an array of objects as expected. If I enter the developer-tools js-console and enter CONFIG  I get an Uncaught ReferenceError: CONFIG is not defined.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CONFIG from './config.json';

class MyComponent extends Component{
    render(){
        //this statement logs as expected
        console.log(CONFIG);

        // the debugger stops execution, but when I enter CONFIG in the
        // dev-tools Console I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: 
        // CONFIG is not defined
        debugger;
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONFIG` is defined inside the module you are writing. It's not a real global variable, it's only "global" inside that module (i.e. that file).

If you really want to make it globally available in browser, try adding `window.CONFIG = CONFIG`.

Comment: Thank you! That's a good point. I can manage to get access to the config when I add it to the module in the class constructor this.config = config. But why does console.log have access to the CONF variable?

Comment: `console.log` can "see" it because it is running *inside* the scope of `CONFIG` (i.e. inside the module). If you try `console.log(CONFIG)` in a different module/file/component, it will fail: probably it'll print `undefined` or throw the same error.